# swagger-ui-express doesn't show css

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui-express

I'm using swagger-ui-express to expose swagger in my Node application.
In my localhost, everything is shown well.
When I run my application on a Kubernetes POD,
I'm missing the styles on the swagger page.

When I inspect the result swagger page (f12) from the server (POD),
I can see that I have:
"docs" folder with swagger-ui.css file inside, but this css file contains **html context** instead of **css**. very strange!

Any idea ?
Thanks!

Here is the code I'm using to expose:

```
    public static exposeSwagger(app: any) {
    const swaggerDefinition = {
      openapi: '3.0.0',
      info: {
        title: 'Express API for JSONPlaceholder',
        version: '1.0.0'
      }
    };

    const options = {
      swaggerDefinition,
      apis: ['./specs/*.yml']
    };

    try {
      const swaggerSpec = swaggerJsDoc(options);
      app.use('/docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec));
    } catch (err) {
      logger.error(err);
    }
  }
```

Here are my dependencies from package.json:
"swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.8",
"swagger-ui-express": "^4.6.3"